# How can I make the greedy.wilks function from klaR work on a post-HCPC data frame?

Tags: r, factominer

So basically I'm using klaR to perform a greedy.wilks on a data frame that I obtained through the HCPC function from factomineR.

Here is my starting data frame (I'm only interested in 1 to 15 variables here) :

```r
> alim[,1:15]
# A tibble: 101 x 15
   poulet boeuf  porc poisson `fruits de mer` `légume vert` `légume racine` `autre légume` féculent crudités pâtisseries `encas sucré` `encas salé`  soda alcool
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>          <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1   3.89 11.8  13.3    2.07             1.76         0.290           14.3            1.94    19.4      7.14        2.6           8.77         5.89 15.1   10.6 
 2   6.33  4.75  2.94  11.7              5.03        13.4             11.4            3.1     14.6     16.8         3.02          2.43         0.76  7.86  15.7 
 3   8.97  2.79  2.56   1.15             4.31        19.1             16.9            1.89    22.6      2.8         8.21          0.81        10.7   9.53   6.64
 4   4.19  6.28  7.08   2.98            13.4         12.3             21.2            1.76    10.8      8.51        3.83          7.3          0.63 10.5    1.91
 5   8.33  3.83  6.61   0.290            2.33         4.73             8.48           2.26    29.9      4.12        7.7           1.81         2.09  4.87  13.2 
 6   4.62  4.48  7.86  11.8              8.13         8.31            21.0            0.81     9.35     7.34        0.46          2.44         5.69  0.7    3.77
 7   0.17  0.79  3.52   5.37             7.04        10.5             29.9           10.9      9.36    17.2         1.28          4.73         2.64 10.6    1.11
 8   8.84  6.77  4.95   0.65             3.22        19.7             17.5           19.8     16.2      4.65        4.93          3.76         5.36  3.82   6.77
 9   1.3   6.8   8.08   1.81             3.3          3.15            24.6            1.5     17.9      0.83        0.44          6.67         3.34  4.55   0.36
10  10.3   4.79  6.51   4.1              6.16        12.2             21.6            3.9      8.63    16.8        12.8           7.01         1.62  0.51  10.1 
# … with 91 more rows
```

I'm now using PCA and HCPC from factomineR :

```r
> alim_pca <- PCA(alim[,1:15], scale.unit = TRUE,graph = FALSE)
> alim_hcpc <- HCPC(alim_pca, nb.clust = 3, graph=FALSE, nb.par = Inf)
```

And I get a new data frame with a cluster column calculated from HCPC :

```r
> alim_types <- alim_hcpc$data.clust
> alim_types
   poulet boeuf  porc poisson fruits de mer légume vert légume racine autre légume féculent crudités pâtisseries encas sucré encas salé  soda alcool clust
1    3.89 11.85 13.32    2.07          1.76        0.29         14.31         1.94    19.40     7.14        2.60        8.77       5.89 15.06  10.56     1
2    6.33  4.75  2.94   11.70          5.03       13.41         11.43         3.10    14.63    16.75        3.02        2.43       0.76  7.86  15.66     2
3    8.97  2.79  2.56    1.15          4.31       19.07         16.92         1.89    22.60     2.80        8.21        0.81      10.70  9.53   6.64     1
4    4.19  6.28  7.08    2.98         13.37       12.28         21.21         1.76    10.84     8.51        3.83        7.30       0.63 10.46   1.91     2
5    8.33  3.83  6.61    0.29          2.33        4.73          8.48         2.26    29.86     4.12        7.70        1.81       2.09  4.87  13.22     1
6    4.62  4.48  7.86   11.77          8.13        8.31         20.98         0.81     9.35     7.34        0.46        2.44       5.69  0.70   3.77     2
7    0.17  0.79  3.52    5.37          7.04       10.49         29.94        10.88     9.36    17.21        1.28        4.73       2.64 10.55   1.11     2
8    8.84  6.77  4.95    0.65          3.22       19.73         17.53        19.82    16.23     4.65        4.93        3.76       5.36  3.82   6.77     2
9    1.30  6.80  8.08    1.81          3.30        3.15         24.58         1.50    17.94     0.83        0.44        6.67       3.34  4.55   0.36     1
10  10.34  4.79  6.51    4.10          6.16       12.22         21.57         3.90     8.63    16.85       12.77        7.01       1.62  0.51  10.12     2
```

Now I want to use greedy.wilks, I tried both "default" and "formula" usage but they both return errors :

```r
> alim_greed <- greedy.wilks(alim_types[,1:15], alim_types$clust)
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:1:36: unexpected symbol
1: alim_types$clust ~ féculent+légume racine
                                       ^
> alim_greed <- greedy.wilks(clust ~ ., data = alim_types)
Error in `[.data.frame`(m, xvars) : undefined columns selected
```

I might be wrong on something but I can't find where.

Comment: My guess is that `greedy.wilks` does not handle column names with spaces well. Try renaming them with underscores `_` or some other character and try again.

Comment: If you post your data using `dput` output, it's much easier to copy into a local environment and work on.  Also, consider using `janitor::clean_names()` as a processing step when loading data.  If @Vincent is correct about the spacing issue, `clean_names()` is a great way to resolve that problem up front.